# Laravel eloquent where not in with where condition not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I want to get total number of ID without $this->id.
I used this. but it is not working.

```
public function edit(Member $member)
{
    $data = DB::table("members")
        ->where('nid_number', '=','7357665970')
        ->whereNotIn('id',$member->id)
        ->count();
    dd($data);
}
```

want to use it on ajax validation on edit. please help

Comment: $member->id is array?

Comment: no. its unique ID number

Comment: `->whereNotIn('id',$member->id)` here `$member->id` it should be an array

Comment: I want all nid which have '7357665970' without $member->nid. It will count all nid_number but not include $member's nid_number. 
can you please help?

Comment: If `$member->id` is a single `integer`, you don't need to use `whereIn()`, `where('id', '!=', $member->id)` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need in this way to check existance during edit**

```
public function edit(Member $member)
{
    if(DB::table("members")->where('nid_number', '=','7357665970')->where('id','!=',$member->id)->exists())
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

*Note: You don't whereNotIn for a single id, it must be an array*

Answer (score 4):

Please try following code

```
public function edit(Member $member)
{
    $data = DB::table("members")
        ->where('nid_number', '=','7357665970')
        ->whereNotIn('id', [$member->id])
        ->count();
    dd($data);
}
```

The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries